# Pass custom properties in Resource in V4

Tags: react-admin

Bit of a newbie here that recently moved to v4. I have some Resources declared using options to pass some custom property. In React Admin 3 syntax:

```
<Resource name='mydata' options={{label: "Mylabel", site: site}} list={MyList} />
```

This is using the options prop to pass down my site property.
Since the props injection is removed in React admin V4 - what is a good way to pass this prop to my list component in V4?

Answer (score 1):

You can still pass the `options` prop to the `Resource` component.

And you can get it like this:

```js
const PostList = () => {
    const { options } = useResourceDefinitions();
    // ... 
}
```

This is somewhat explained in the Upgrade Guide from v3 to v4:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html#custom-menus-should-get-resource-definition-from-context